# Eager loading child collections with the help of Future and HQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, eager-loading

I am trying to load the child collection of a child of the entity I am selecting. I am trying to mimic [this way](http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate) of doing it, basically creating two future queries and then enumerating one of them. This should lead to two queries to the database:

```
var idd = session.CreateQuery("from ItemDeliveryDetail idd " + 
                              "join fetch idd.ItemDelivery " +
                              "left join fetch idd.SupplierInvoice " +
                              "where idd.Id = 21931828")
                 .Future<ItemDeliveryDetail>();

var spc = session.CreateQuery("from SpecialCondition spc " +
                              "where spc.ItemDelivery " +
                              "in (select idd.ItemDelivery " +
                                  "from ItemDeliveryDetail idd " +
                                  "where idd.Id = 21931828)")
                 .Future<SpecialCondition>();

var result = idd.ToList();
```

The last line indeed results in two queries to the database. The queries are exactly what I expect (They are rather lengthy and I don't think they are relevant to the question, but if you would like to see them, I pasted them [here](http://pastebin.com/dYKmzfHg)).

Problem is, the results of those two queries are not combined, i.e. the following enumeration will still query the database for the `SpecialCondition`s of each `ItemDelivery`:

```
foreach (var itemDeliveryDetail in result)
{
    foreach (var specialCondition in itemDeliveryDetail.ItemDelivery
                                                       .SpecialConditions)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Don't you need 3 queries? One to get the ItemDeliveryDetail, one to get the ItemDelivery, and one to get the SpecialConditions?

Comment: I don't think so because I am eagerly fetching the `ItemDelivery` in the `ItemDeliveryDetail` query.

Comment: @MerickOWA: But to be sure, I just tested it - and it really doesn't change anything.

Comment: hrm only other thought is that you might need to fetch the ItemDelivery in your second query as well or maybe nHibernate can't match the SpecialConditions up to the ItemDelivery in your first query.

Comment: @MerickOWA: I also tried that (eager fetching `ItemDelivery` in the `SpecialCondition` query). Didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query does **not** load the `ItemDelivery.SpecialConditions` collections; only an unused list of SpecialConditions.

I agree with Rippo in that using `batch-size` is usually cleaner and more performant, *even if it results in one or two more roundtrips*.

That said, your second query should be:

```
var spc = session.CreateQuery("from ItemDelivery id " +
                              "join fetch id.SpecialCondition "
                              "where id in (select idd.ItemDelivery " +
                                           "from ItemDeliveryDetail idd " +
                                           "where idd.Id = 21931828)"
             .Future<ItemDelivery>();
```

Comment: This only works if you change `Future<SpecialCondition>` to `Future<ItemDelivery>`. But then it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

One quick win might be to add `batch-size=50` to the bag mapping between `ItemDelivery` and `SpecialConditions`.

<strike>However I suggest you read this blog "[Eagerly loading entity associations efficiently with NHibernate](http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate)" post from Ayende as it might provide you with the answer you are looking for.</strike>

You are facing the classic select n + 1 problem here. I would rather have 1 or maybe 2 more trips to the database rather than a big `cartesian product` resultset. I am sure this will be the most performant route.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it is a bit off. I know that I am facing the N + 1 problem here. In fact, the only purpose of using `Future` in my code is to avoid it. The blog post you are suggesting is the one I already linked to in my question. I am also pretty sure that `batch-size=50` doesn't solve the problem I have. In short: I want to have N queries upfront that return all necessary data where N is independent of the rows returned. Currently I have two queries (N=2), one for `ItemDeliveryDetail` and one for `SpecialCondition`.

Comment: Oops sorry about blog post! However setting the `batch-size` will most likely be the most performant rather than having a huge cartessian resultset of `parent->children->grandchildren`

Comment: Problem is, I need all of the returned data, so I don't think setting the batch size does any good. Or am I understanding batch-size wrong?

Comment: Swings and roundabouts, if you need all the returned data and there are not too many columns or there are not 100's of children/grandchildren then go with what you want. However to save a lot of repeated data transmitting down the wire then use lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same base query twice which I think is your problem.

```
var idd = session.CreateQuery("from ItemDeliveryDetail idd " + 
                          "join fetch idd.ItemDelivery " +
                          "left join fetch idd.SupplierInvoice " +
                          "where idd.Id = 21931828")
             .Future<ItemDeliveryDetail>();

var spc = session.CreateQuery("from ItemDeliveryDetail idd " + 
                          "join fetch idd.ItemDelivery id " +
                          "join fetch id.SpecialCondition spc " +
                         "where idd.Id = 21931828")
             .Future<ItemDeliveryDetail>();

var result = idd.ToList();
```

Yes I realise this may cause a cartesian product for you but I have had good success using this technique.

Comment: This approach could be simplified even further to only use a single query, because `SupplierInvoice` is many to one from `ItemDeliveryDetail` to `SupplierInvoice`, i.e. every `ItemDeliveryDetail` only has one `SupplierInvoice`. Your two queries have no advantage over the one query I just described and that huge cartesian product is the reason why I didn't go with one query in the first place...